# JTextArea to file

Tags: java, swing, file, jtextarea, bufferedwriter

I want to save text from a JTextArea to a file, the code below works perfectly fine but the only thing is that the line breaks aren't converted. This means no matter how many lines I have in the JTextArea, they are all displayed in one line in the text file.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
writer.append(textArea.getText());
writer.close();
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Which editor are you using to display the contents of the file?

Comment: Are they real line breaks (ie, user hit Enter)? or are they just wrapping line breaks?

Answer (score 4):

A decent solution is to use the Writer that comes with the JTextArea itself. Hang on,... example to come...

**Edit** Example below:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)); // true for append
textArea.write(writer);
writer.close();
```